# sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'except'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Al ejecutar este query de abajo, me sale el siguiente mensaje de error: 
"Mens. 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 9
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'except'."
Si ejecuto las porciones de query por separado, sí obtengo resultado, pero al usar el operador ''Except'', n

```
select top 200 f.CodigoCliente, c.Nombre1, c.ApePaterno, c.ApeMaterno, c.Telefono1, c.Telefono2--, SUM(f.Total) 
from CLIENTE as c inner join factura as f on
c.CodigoEmp=f.CodigoEmp and
c.CodigoCliente=f.CodigoCliente
where f.SituacionFactura='10'
group by f.CodigoCliente, c.Nombre1, c.ApePaterno, c.ApeMaterno, c.Telefono1, c.Telefono2
order by SUM(total) desc

except

select f.CodigoCliente, c.Nombre1, c.ApePaterno, c.ApeMaterno, c.Telefono1, c.Telefono2--, SUM(f.Total) 
from factura as f left join facturadetalle as fd on
f.CodigoEmp=fd.CodigoEmp and
f.empresadestino=fd.empresadestino and
f.TipoDocumento=fd.TipoDocumento and
f.NumeroSerie=fd.NumeroSerie and
f.NumeroFactura=fd.NumeroFactura
inner join CLIENTE as c on
f.CodigoEmp=c.CodigoEmp and
f.CodigoCliente=c.CodigoCliente
where fd.CodigoTipoProducto='03'
and fd.CodigoProducto in ('276','872','1082','1083','1084')
and f.SituacionFactura='10'
group by f.CodigoCliente, c.Nombre1, c.ApePaterno, c.ApeMaterno, c.Telefono1, c.Telefono2
order by SUM(total) desc
```

Comment: Prueba a quitar el `order by SUM(total) desc` antes del `except`.

Comment: Pero si le quito el `order by SUM(Total) desc` ya no me va a calcular los primeros 200 clientes que consumieron más.

Comment: Ok. ¿Has probado a poner las consultas entre paréntesis?

Comment: Sí, las he puesto entre paréntesis y tampoco me arroja resultado.

Answer (score 0):

no uses except, usa el NOT IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1
WHERE id  NOT IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM Tab1 
    WHERE int_attribute_of_Tab1>0
)
```

es mas practico y te va a funcionar

Comment: Al colocar NOT in, tampoco me sale respuesta.